# file deleting in nitrous.IO

Tags: nitrousio

I am playing with a repo I've cloned in nitrous.IO.

I mistakenly created a "README_UPDATE" file without the .md extension when I was planning to push my commit to github. I've tried to 'rm README_UPDATE' with no success in the command prompt; and right click file delete is not working in either nitrous.io on the web IDE or their google app extension.

I've also tried 'ls' to make sure I was in the right directory just in case anyone is asking.

I don't want to delete all my work, so is their any other options for me?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried right clicking the file and selecting 'rename'?